# Changing column from text to integer with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

My table has a text column and I'd like to change to an integer. The existing text column contains values that can be converted to an integer. I don't want to change the column name.

How can I safely do this using code first without losing my data?

One option would be to create a new, temporary column. Copy the values. And then delete the old column and rename the new one. But I'm just not that sure what Entity Framework will decide to do with those changes.

Comment: On SQL Server, a simple ALTER statement will coerce the text to integers. Have you tried changing the property to `int` and adding a migration?

Comment: @madreflection: No, I haven't. I'd like to know more because I'd risk losing my data if I don't get it right.

Comment: You don't have to run the migration to see if it might be on the right track.

Comment: @madreflection: Did you find a GitHub discussion about this? Are you able to post a URL?

Comment: Regarding `-WhatIf`, I found this: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/1775

Comment: ...but I suspect that wasn't what you thought I was talking about.

Comment: You don't have to run `Update-Database` to get an initial sense of whether it might be right or not. Change the property to `int` and run `Add-Migration`. If you don't like it, you can delete the migration; no harm, no foul. If it looks good, make a copy of the database, point your connection string over there, and run `Update-Database` to see if it does what you want (with `-Verbose` to check the SQL after the fact). If you don't like it, drop the copy; no harm, no foul.

Comment: @madreflection: I'm going to try. I have a bunch of changes I need to make in the source code too.

Comment: @madreflection: I made the needed changes. I added the migration to my question. It looks like it might work. But I'd like to be more certain.

Comment: It's pretty much what I was expecting it to generate. It doesn't drop and recreate the column. That's good. I'd still run it against a copy to validate it, and you should take a backup of the real database if/when you decide to run it there just to be safe.

Comment: @madreflection: I ran it on our demo database. As long as the values can be converted, it converts the old data over. Thanks.

Comment: That's great news. You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

So, I simply changed the column definition from:

```
[Display(Name = "Bill of Lading")]
[Required]
[StringLength(80)]
public string BillOfLading { get; set; }
```

To:

```
[Display(Name = "Bill of Lading")]
public int BillOfLading { get; set; }
```

I patched up my code so it would compile with the new type, and I added a migration, which looked like this:

```
public partial class TransloadingDetailBillOfLadingToInt : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
            name: "BillOfLading",
            table: "TransloadingDetails",
            type: "int",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(80)",
            oldMaxLength: 80);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "BillOfLading",
            table: "TransloadingDetails",
            type: "nvarchar(80)",
            maxLength: 80,
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(int),
            oldType: "int");
    }
}
```

I was able to run `update-database` on a smaller, demo database we have. On my first attempt, I had a column value that could not be converted. In that instance, I got an error and no data was lost. A good sign!

After correcting the data, I ran it again and the text columns were converted to integers. All the existing data was correctly converted. And then the same thing on my main database.

So, at least in the case of converting a text column to an integer column, where the data can be converted, this works just as you'd want it to work.